# firewire emulation for virtual machines

Tags: audio, virtual-machine, firewire, audio-recording

As is well known by people that have the joy of having a FireWire professional audio interface, virtual machines (VirtualBox, VmWare, etc.) cannot access FireWire devices.

I'm wondering if there are ongoing projects to support firewire emulation over network bridges (tun or tap devices) so that these connections can be provided to virtual machines?

Comment: sorry, that is not true. All the high-range audio interfaces are exclusively Firewire (M-Audio, Presonus, Motu, etc.). The only USB audio interfaces are for the low-range and hobbists market. Niche as it might be, Firewire has clearly won in the professional audio and video market

Comment: I guess we will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life inside of a VirtualMachine is full of jitter and lag. If you're going to actually take advantage of professional gear, you need a dedicated machine.

Firewire it's self though, very simple hardware, copies memory from one host to another. Very simple and very fast. Downside is that to put that in a VM, the memory address would have to be mangled for each and every transaction. I don't think anyone is working on this idea for that reason.